# Restore a discounted product price for a specific shipping method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, shipping-method

I am trying to find a solution to the following issue.
I have been using Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing in order to apply a 25% discount for a specific product category.
Then, I need to remove that discount if shipping option will be local_pickup.
I thought I can tweak the following code. It is missing something somewhere, so I am asking you for help.

```
function discount_table(){
// Set $cat_in_cart to false
$cat_in_cart = false;

// Loop through all products in the Cart        
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    if ( has_term( 'category_1', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $cat_in_cart = true;
        break;
    }
}

    $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    $sconto_label = "";
    if($total >= 300){
        $sconto_label=15;       
    }elseif($total >= 220){
        $sconto_label=10;
    }elseif($total >= 150){
        $sconto_label=8;
    }elseif($total >= 100){
        $sconto_label=4;
    }
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = explode(':',$chosen_methods[0]);

    if($chosen_shipping[0]=='local_pickup' && !$cat_in_cart){
        $sconto_label=25;
    }
    else if ($chosen_shipping[0]=='local_pickup' && $cat_in_cart){
        $sconto_label=25;
// there should be something here or not?
    }
    $sconto_cliente = (($total*$sconto_label)/100);
    if($sconto_label!="")
        $sconto_cliente_net = ($sconto_loison/1.1);
        WC()->cart->add_fee( "Discount ($sconto_label%)", -$sconto_cliente_net, false );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','discount_table' );
```

Is there a way to restore original price of one or more item of a specific category that have been already discounted when in cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore cart items price based on a product category and on a specific chosen shipping method, try the following *(for Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_default_price_as_cart_item_custom_data', 50, 3 );
function add_default_price_as_cart_item_custom_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){
    // HERE define your product category(ies)
    $categories = array('t-shirts');

    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

        // The WC_Product Object
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

        // Get product default base price
        $price = (float) $product->get_price();

        // Set the Product default base price as custom cart item data
        $cart_item_data['default_price'] = $price;
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'restore_cart_item_price', 900, 1 );
function restore_cart_item_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // HERE set the targeted Chosen Shipping method
    $targeted_shipping_method = 'local_pickup';

    // Get the chosen shipping method
    $chosen_methods            = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_method_id = explode(':', reset($chosen_methods) );
    $chosen_shipping_method    = reset($chosen_shipping_method_id);

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( $targeted_shipping_method == $chosen_shipping_method && isset($cart_item['default_price']) ){
            // Set back the default cart item price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['default_price']);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> **Note:** When Using a **negative fee** *(a cart discount)*, the tax is always applied.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately, having Woocommerce Dynamic Pricing activated and the previous piece of code above in functions.php - I need it as a discount scale to apply in cart - your piece of code seems not to work.
E.g.: a cart including two items, one belonging to a category without discount and another item belonging to a discounted category. This latter keeps its discounted price, 3,75€ instead of 5€ - shown in a cart row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Your piece of code seems to work, but no properly. I do not think it's your script's fault. I need to reload cart page in order for cart rows and values to be updated. Is there an alternative to do it instead of manually page reload?
Ok for taxes to be calculated in this case.

Comment: @alemarengo With the hooks that I am using, there is normally no problem of data refresh as `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` is ajax powered. I have lightly updated my answer code, but I don't think that it will change something. So there is something else that is making a problem there. Now mostly everything can be done depending on your skills and on the time to be spent (and on the budget).

Answer (score 0):

I dig a little bit your code and made some changes. Found a bug thanks to a super dev! Here's the code:

```
function discount_table(){
$cat_in_cart = false;
$tot_cat = 0;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

    if ( has_term( 'cat1', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $cat_in_cart = true;
        $tot_cat_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
        $tot_cat_qty = $cart_item['quantity'];
        $tot_cat +=  $tot_cat_price * $tot_cat_qty;
        //break;
/* commented here, thanks to Michael Ramin: break will stop execution of the loop after found the first product belonging to the category; what if you have more than one? so remove break instruction */
    }
}
    global $product;
    $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    $discount_label = "";
    if($total >= 300){
        $discount_label=15;     
    }elseif($total >= 220){
        $discount_label=10;
    }elseif($total >= 150){
        $discount_label=8;
    }elseif($total >= 100){
        $discount_label=4;
    }
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = explode(':',$chosen_methods[0]);

    if($chosen_shipping[0]=='local_pickup'){
        $discount_label=25;
    }
    $discount_brand = ($total-$tot_cat)*$discount_label/100;
    if($discount_label!=""){
        $discount_brand_net = ($discount_brand/1.1);
        if($discount_brand_net != 0) // show discount only if != 0; it may happen if cart includes only targeted category products;
            WC()->cart->add_fee( "Discount ($discount_label%)", -$discount_brand_net, false );
    }   
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','discount_table' );
```